# How to save a list of numbers in a .txt file in java?

Tags: java

So, I'm trying to create a program in java that saves a list of numbers by taking them from the user-input from the JOptionPane, and store it into a text file. The code that I have works nice but it can't save all the numbers. I dont know what I am doing wrong. Here is what I have so far

```
package savenumbers;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
public class SaveNumbers {
    public static void personInput() {
        int contador, numeros, array[];
        numeros = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("¿How many numbers?: "));
        array = new int[numeros];
        for (contador = 0; contador < numeros; contador++)
            array[contador] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter " + numeros + " numbers"));

        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("./"));
        Component yourWindowName = null;
        int actionDialog = chooser.showSaveDialog(yourWindowName); //where the dialog should render
        if (actionDialog == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File fileName = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile() + ".txt"); //opens a filechooser dialog allowing you to choose where to store the file and appends the .txt mime type
            if (fileName == null)
                return;
            if (fileName.exists()) //if filename already exists
            {
                actionDialog = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(yourWindowName,
                    "Replace?");
                if (actionDialog == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) //open a new dialog to confirm the replacement file
                    return;
            }
            try {
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));

                out.write(numeros);
                out.close(); //write the data to the file and close, please refer to what madProgrammer has explained in the comments here about where the file may not close correctly. 
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.err.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                personInput();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read the Help Center to understand [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Specifically, how to provide a [MCVE].

Comment: Take a look at the [JavaDocs for FileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html), you can pass it an `append` flag or, if you want to write a sequence of numbers, then you'll need a loop

Comment: What is this comment referring to?  `//write the data to the file and close, please refer to what madProgrammer has explained in the comments here about where the file may not close correctly.`   Is this code copied from another Q or A?

Comment: Indeed it is - http://stackoverflow.com/a/27643170/139985 !!  Last time I checked, copying and creating were different activities.  So what you are actually doing here is asking >>us<< to turn an incomplete example program you have found into working code.  OFF-TOPIC!!

Comment: *"I dont know what I am doing wrong."*  Technically, or morally?  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using BufferedWriter works with one character at a time, so in the `try` block, loop through the `array` of numbers and convert them to `Integer` that get written out to the file, flushed and closed:

```
    try {
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
        for (int numero : array) {
            out.write(Integer.toString(numero) + "\n");
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
```